# How to run ElasticSearch on port 80?

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I run ElasticSearch on port 80? I modified the **elasticsearch.yml** file to point to port **80**,  but it doesn't seem to work.

I am however able to run it on other ports like **8000**, but when we are pointing to port **80** it doesn't seem to work.

```
http.port: 8000 (This works)
http.port: 80 (Doesn't seem to work)
```

Comment: which elasticsearch version you use?

Comment: @code-blue Pls add `/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log` output to your question. You likely have some permission issues

Comment: I was able to run ES on port 80. Probably you have something else running on port 80. You could check it on Linux with lsof -i :80 which program is running on port 80

Comment: also consider ports below 1024 require admin privileges

Answer (score 3):

In order to change port 80 you need root privileges (as of with all the ports underneath 1024)

You can forward the connection as follow

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8060 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8060
```

Source: [source](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fishkb/how-do-i-use-port-80-or-443-on-my-server-as-a-non-root-user-on-linux-701268563.html)

Comment: Perfect solution 