# Change http_port number of Elasticsearch to 80

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to setup ELK on Ubuntu 18.04 and I only have port 80 for now to test Elasticsearch dashboard so I modified the elasticsearch.yml as below

```
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
network.host: x.x.x.x
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
http.port: 80
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
```

But in logstash logs it says

```
[2019-05-10T08:46:01,216][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://x.x.x.x:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://x.x.x.x:9200/][Manticore::SocketException] Connection refused (Connection refused)"}
```

I think it is trying to find elasticsearch on 9200 ..

Any help on this will be appreciated

Comment: Also note that ES cannot bind to port 80 by default, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31934292/4604579) for how to achieve it. Then as @aHockstein showed, make sure to also modify your Logstash config file

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the output port of logstash, you can look it up [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-examples.html).

```
input { stdin { } }

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
  }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }  <-- change this
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change http.port into elasticsearch.yml file from config directory